# how to find the inside value of logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I m doing sums in chemistry of first order reaction.
In it,
0.521 = log(0.3/C)
Then how to find the value of c??
The value is c= 0.09

Comment: This can be rearranged to $10^{0.521} = 0.3/C$

Comment: Is it log bade 10 or log base e?  Either way, you raise the base to both sides of the equatio. Ie $10^{0.521} = 10^{\log (.3/C)} = .3/C $.  So $C = .3/10^{0.521}$.

Comment: $10^{\log w} = w $ by definition.  So if you ever have $foo  = \log (somethingtosolve) $.  You can do $10^{foo} =10^{\log (somethigtosolve)} = somethingtosolve  $ and solve from there.

Comment: The same thing fo $\ln $ except you Rais $e $ to the power instead of 10.  And in the few cases where you have $\log_b something $ you raise $b $ to the power.

Comment: $10^{.521} = =3.3189445755$ so $C = .3/ =3.3189445755 = .09$ seems about right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the properties of logarithms write the equation as:
$$
0.51=\log (0.3) -\log C
$$
and solve for $\log C$
$$
\log C= \log (0.3)-0.51
$$

Now exponentiate the basis of the logarithm to find $C$.